# Need to fix code to find first name, last name from employees by using department name

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

The code below is used to find first name, last name from employees by using department name. I got error: Error(13,8): PLS-00103 But I have no idea how to fix it. Any advice? Thanks in advance

```
create or replace procedure xx(a in varchar2)
as
cursor b is select department_name, first_name, last_name from employees;
c employees%rowtype;
begin
open b;
loop
    fetch b into c;
    exit when b%notfound;
        if a = c.department_name then
        dbms_output.put_line(c.first_name);
        dbms_output.put_line(c.last_name);
        elseif DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c.last_name);
        end if;
end loop;
close b;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error(13,8) is in the line below

```
elseif DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c.last_name);
```

you are using elsif but doesnt have any conditions to test.
if you dont have any more conditions to compare/test, you might as well use else rather than elsif

```
create or replace procedure xx(a in varchar2)
as
cursor b is select department_name, first_name, last_name from employees;
c employees%rowtype;
begin
open b;
loop
    fetch b into c;
    exit when b%notfound;
        if a = c.department_name then
            dbms_output.put_line(c.first_name);
            dbms_output.put_line(c.last_name);
        else 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c.last_name);
        end if;
end loop;
close b;
end;
```

note: syntax errors shows which line and column you may have gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this one below:

```
create or replace procedure xx(a in varchar2)
as
cursor b is select department_name, first_name, last_name from employees;
c b%rowtype;
begin
open b;
loop
    fetch b into c;
    exit when b%notfound;
        if a = c.department_name then
        dbms_output.put_line(c.first_name);
        dbms_output.put_line(c.last_name);
        elseif DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c.last_name);
        end if;
end loop;
close b;
end;
```